# print json result to google maps

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, google-maps

I have index.php and ajax.php.

When the page loaded ajax function returning a json data from ajax.php. Ajax.php is working. I can get json data. The map is loading firstly than ajax function so I get variable json is not defined error. İf I use json data result directly.

For example `var json=[{{"id":48,"title":"a","lng":"28.6643180847168","lat":"41.0327529907227"}]` my code is working. Firstly the map is loading so it gives an error.

Which should I use different method?  I hope I could have explained enough.

**This is my json data result:**

```
[{"id":48,"title":"a","lng":"28.6643180847168","lat":"41.0327529907227"}, 
{"id":46,"title":"b","lng":"28.6722145080566","lat":"41.0330085754395 "}, 
{"id":44,"title":"c","lng":"28.6628570556641","lat":"41.032169342041 "}, 
{"id":43,"title":"d","lng":"28.6649876832962","lat":"41.0323740058176 "}];
```

**This is index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one"></div>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'ajax.php',
                success:function(data){         
                    var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                    $("#one").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
        var map;
    var json=$("#one").text();
function initialize() { 
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(json[0]['lat'],json[0]['lng'])
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  // Looping through all the entries from the JSON data
  for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { 
    var obj = json[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat,obj.lng),
      map: map
    });   
    var clicker = addClicker(marker, obj.title);
  } 
  function addClicker(marker, content) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      if (infowindow) {infowindow.close();}
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);    
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I put returning lat and long values to on the map. it may help someone.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <script>
    var map;
 function initialize() {
    var url ="ajax.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function( data ) {
                var lat = [];
        var lng = [];
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                        lat.push(val.lat);
            lng.push(val.lng);  });
 var mapOptions = {
zoom: 15,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat[0],lng[0])
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
for(var i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) { 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i],lng[i]),
  map: map
});   

 } });};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);                 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code, it works on my eviroment.

```
  $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",//please check this.
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",//check this
                url: "http://localhost/MyTESTWEBSITE/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",//my json data
                success: function(data) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d); //please check this   
                for (var i = 0; i < result.DATA.length; i++) {
                    var obj = result.DATA[i];
                    //to do:Put obj.lat, obj.lng to google map
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        });
```

JSON DATA From .net

```
 [WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {

    string str = "{\"DATA\":[{\"id\":43,\"title\":\"d\",\"lng\":\"121.6649876832962\",\"lat\":\"23.0323740058176\"}]}";
    return str;
}
```

You can also use this link to check JSON Format
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: You are right, I tried as you said. But markers dont create on the map. İf I write a for example json = [{"id":48,"title":"a","lng":"28.6643180847168","lat":"41.0327529907227"},
{"id":46,"title":"b","lng":"28.6722145080566","lat":"41.0330085754395 "},
   {"id":44,"title":"c","lng":"28.6628570556641","lat":"41.032169342041 "},
{"id":43,"title":"d","lng":"28.6649876832962","lat":"41.0323740058176 "}];  data  markers are created. Otherwise markers dont create.

Comment: Do you check the content of obj.lat && obj.lng from php? if you alert() the content, is it right?

Comment: I just want to learn how to use json data result to google maps. My code isn't working now. When the page is loaded in both the map and ajax loading so I cant use json data result on the map.

Comment: Add  this  to your javascript code to see if any error happened.                                                                   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);

Comment: I updated my question. it may be more clear. Just my problem is the map loading before ajax function. So it gives json is not defined error.

Comment: Thanks for helping I think you didnt understand me correctly. My ajax is working no any problem. Firstly google map is loading to page later ajax function is calling json data. So it throws undefined json data. İf ajax function is running before google maps that will create markers on map.

Comment: I had finished more than ten google map project. Every time I initiated google map engine first and then had ajax calls.It worked fine every time. This should not be problem. You said you wrote a JSON sample code and it works fine. Do you put the JSON sample code int PHP? or you hard code in js?